# Java if else with nested loop

Tags: java, eclipse, loops, command-line-interface

I am having some problem with my java assignment and currently am stuck at the nested if else statement.I am actually trying to get an input age from the user and store in as a variable.After executing my code i am getting error when i run the program.Am i doing this correctly or is there some other way to program this?

Error message that i got

```
    Enter your selection: 
    1
    You have selected No.1
    Please enter your age**Exception in thread "main" 
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed
    at java.util.Scanner.ensureOpen(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Assignment.main(Assignment.java:48)**
```

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println(
       "1. Add player" + "\n" +
       "2.Display transaction" + "\n" +
       "3.Begin the ride");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
    char selection = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);
    sc.close();
    switch(selection)  {
    case '1' :
        System.out.println("You have selected No.1");
        break;
    case '2' :
        System.out.println("You have selected No.2" );
        break;
    case '3' :
        System.out.println("You have selected No.3" );
        break;  
    default: 
        System.out.println("Please make a selection");
        break; 
   }
   if (selection=='1') {  
        int age=0;
        System.out.print("Please enter your age");
        age = sc.nextInt();
        while (age<100) {
            age+=age;
        }
    }       
    else if (selection=='2') {
        System.out.println("Display daily transaction");
    }
    else if (selection=='3') {
        System.out.println("Begin the ride");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
    }
}
```

Comment: "i am getting error when i run the program" - What is the error message? Error messages contain important information that gives you a hint about what's wrong, so it's important to share the error message, so that we can tell you what it means if you don't understand it yourself.

Comment: thanks for correcting, i have already updated the post with the error message.

Comment: You closed the scanner and then tried to read more stuff from it.

Comment: Why are you closing the `Scanner` at all?  It's not like you're reading from a file, and typically you want to avoid closing the major input stream anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can reduce this code to a very good extent, i haven't removed nested-if statements, which you can by moving all execution under case statements.

This program will terminate if option entered is not a number, this can also be improved by reading it as a string and checking is its one of the valid options (map's key set).

```
import java.util.LinkedHashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class SwitchCase {

    public static Map<Integer, String> options = new LinkedHashMap<Integer, String>();
    static {
        options.put(1, "Add player");
        options.put(2, "Display transaction");
        options.put(3, "Begin the ride");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (Integer option : options.keySet()) {
            System.out.println(option + ". " + options.get(option));
        }
        System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
        int selection = sc.nextInt();
        switch (selection) {
        case 1:
        case 2:
        case 3:
            System.out.println("You have selected No." + selection);
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("Please make a selection");
            break;
        }
        if (selection == 1) {
            int age = 0;
            System.out.print("Please enter your age : ");
            age = sc.nextInt();
            while (age < 100) {
                age += age;
            }
            System.out.println(age);
        } else if (selection == 2) {
            System.out.println(options.get(selection));
        } else if (selection == 3) {
            System.out.println(options.get(selection));
        } else {
            System.out.println("Please enter a valid input!");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read basic Java so that you can learn programs better.

Answer (score 0):

switch case is a type of nested if else.we can use switch in place of nested if else.you need not to use both switch case and nested if else simultaneously.
you can write your code like this.

```
public static void main(String args[]) {

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("1. Add player" + "\n" +
       "2.Display transaction" + "\n" +
       "3.Begin the ride");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Enter your selection: ");
    char selection = sc.findInLine(".").charAt(0);

    switch(selection)  {

    case '1' :
        System.out.println("You have selected No.1");
        int age=0;
        System.out.print("Please enter your age");
        age = sc.nextInt();
        while (age<100) {
            age+=age;
        }
        System.out.print(age);
        break;

    case '2' :

        System.out.println("You have selected No.2" );
        System.out.println("Display daily transaction");
        break;

    case '3' :

        System.out.println("You have selected No.3" );
        System.out.println("Begin the ride");
        break;  

    default: 

        System.out.println("Please make a selection");
        System.out.println("Please enter a valid input");
        break; 

   }
    sc.close();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The exception is pretty clear on the problem: `java.lang.IllegalStateException: Scanner closed`

Before your code enters the `switch`, you're closing the scanner with `sc.close();`. But later on you're trying to read from it again:

```
if (selection=='1') {  
    int age=0;
    System.out.print("Please enter your age");
    age = sc.nextInt();  // <---- Here
    while (age<100) {
        age+=age;
    }
}
```

But this will fail if the scanner is already closed. To solve this, you can simply put the line `sc.close()` to the end of your `main`.

As an alternative you could wrap everything into a [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html) block, so that you don't have to care about closing the scanner anymore because it will be closed automatically after leaving the block.